# scala function with repeated parameters

Tags: function, scala, capitalize

I see that it possible to uses the following syntax for method that take parameters of a repeated type:

```
def capitalizeAll( args: String*) = {
  args.map { args => args.capitalize }
}
```

However I was wondering how an function can be used instead of "args => args.capitalize"

for example (does not work):

```
def func(s: String): String = { s.capitalize }
def capitalizeAll2( args: String*) = {
    args.map { func( args ) }
}
```

how can I make this work?
Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no magic:

```
def func(s: String): String = { s.capitalize }
def capitalizeAll2( args: String*) = {
    args.map { arg => func( arg ) }
}
```

Here I gave `arg` name to currently processed string (out of all `args` strings). Your first example works only because of shadowing (all strings are `args` and current string given the same name, which just shadows original).

Almost no magic...

```
def capitalizeAll3( args: String*) = {
    args.map(func)
}
```

The latest example uses syntax sugar to apply function with only one parameter to args.

Comment: You should probably also mention `args.map(_.capitalize)` - maybe it is what he actually wants (just a wild guess).